# Go - JSON-RPC - "too many colons"

Tags: http, communication, go, json-rpc

I'm trying to call a [HTTP JSON-RPC server for Bitcoin](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/How_to_use_the_API,_JSON-RPC) using Go (not on GAE), but I get error of

```
dial tcp http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8332: too many colons in address
```

or

```
dial ip http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8332: lookup http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8332: no such host
```

I tried various [network configurations](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dial), but couldn't get anything going. When I just typed the address into the browser, I got a response from the server:

```
{"result":null,"error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error"},"id":null}
```

Which looks like a proper response for an empty call.

How do I correctly call that HTTP JSON-RPC server in Go?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use brackets around the host like this:

```
[user:pass@127.0.0.1]:8332
```

Reference:

http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/ipsock.go?s=2247:2304#L68

Comment: It's crazy - but it works! Thanks!