# How to properly call JSON-RPC in Go?

Tags: json, request, go, rpc, json-rpc

I've been trying various configurations in order to call [a simple JSON-RPC server for Bitcoin](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Elis-API#Example_Request) in Go, but didn't manage to get anywhere.

In Python, the entire code looks like:

```
from jsonrpc import ServiceProxy
access = ServiceProxy("http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8332")
print access.getinfo()
```

But in Go, I seem to be bumping into erros like ["too many colons in address"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854682/go-json-rpc-too-many-colons), or "no such host". I've tried using both of the packages rpc and rpc/jsonrpc, using methods Dial and DialHTTP, using various network parameters and still can't get anywhere.

So, how do I properly call a JSON-RPC server in Go?

Comment: wasn't this the solution to your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854682/go-json-rpc-too-many-colons

Comment: No, that solved only a part of the problem I think, I still get error of "no such host" and other ones depending on which of many different configurations I tried. That's why I'd appreciate some working code, as checking options such as whether to put "http://" in the address, which network to use, whether to use rpc or jsonrpc, whether to call Dial or DialHTTP produces way too many options to try and tweak all of them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [jsonrpc](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/jsonrpc/) package doesn't support json-rpc over HTTP at the moment. So, you can't use that, sorry.

But the [jsonrpc specification](http://json-rpc.org/wiki/specification) is quite simple and it's probably quite easy to write your own `jsonrpchttp` (oh, I hope you know a better name) package.

I was able to call "getinfo" succesfully using the following (horrible) code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    data, err := json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{
        "method": "getinfo",
        "id":     1,
        "params": []interface{}{},
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Marshal: %v", err)
    }
    resp, err := http.Post("http://bob:secret@127.0.0.1:8332",
        "application/json", strings.NewReader(string(data)))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Post: %v", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("ReadAll: %v", err)
    }
    result := make(map[string]interface{})
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &result)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unmarshal: %v", err)
    }
    log.Println(result)
}
```

Maybe you can clean it up a bit by implementing the [rpc.ClientCodec](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/#ClientCodec) interface (see [jsonrpc/client.go](http://tip.golang.org/src/pkg/net/rpc/jsonrpc/client.go) for an example). Then you can take advantage of Go's [rpc](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/) package.

Comment: Hmm, you seem to have some old imports that changed a bit - "encoding/json" to "json" and "net/http" to "http". Asides that, thanks a lot! As for writing my own library, well, I'd like to do that, but I don't think I understand what should go where in the jsonrpc package. Probably should get some repo started though, since as I can see there are a couple people having the same problem.

Comment: I am using the latest tip at the moment. Those imports will change pretty soon when Go 1 is released. Btw, I have also submitted a bug report for this on the Go issue tracker, but the priority was changed to "Later", so a separate package might be a good idea at the moment.

Comment: Updated the code with a server implementation. Don't know much about the rpc codecs though, so based my implementation on http package a bit (registering functions to be called for specific methods and then executing them).