# Golang net Dial user:pass@ip:port gives: no such host

Tags: http, go, httpconnection

I'm trying to connect to a proxy server to start an HTTP CONNECT tunnel. The proxy server uses authentication. This code however fails to work:

```
conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "[user:pass@111.222.333.444]:5555")
```

Even though the host exists, I get an error:

```
"dial tcp: lookup user:pass@111.222.333.444: no such host"
```

The string format I'm using was described in this post. Can't seem to get it to work though.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858209/6767074

Comment: What is that `user:pass@` for?

Comment: Basic authentication for the proxy server. Without it I get an '407 Proxy Authentication Required' response.

Comment: `tcp` doesn't know about basic auth and doesn't care either, you need to use a http-client for that.

Comment: Oh oke, so I have to add the credentials somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, to the http-connection (or to whoever handles the proxy-connection, I don't know much about the proxy protocol)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661511/setting-up-proxy-for-http-client for an example connecting to an HTTP server through a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the problem. The `net.Dial()` method wasn't the one concerned with proxy authentication.

I just had to fill in the "Proxy-Authorization" header of the request before calling for am HTTP response. So my TCP address became:

```
conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "111.222.333.444:5555")
```