# Connect and maintain connection to socks5 proxy server with authentication

Tags: go, proxy, socks

I'm trying to dial using credentials and maintain a connection with a socks5 proxy server in Go.

This works nicely if I have IP authorisation set up with the proxy provider, however there is no way pass any auth credentials using net.Dial function in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net"
)

func main() {

    dst, err := net.Dial("tcp", "11.22.33.44:1111")
    if err != nil {
        panic("Dial Error:" + err.Error())
    }

    dst.Close()
}
```

Go has a useful proxy library and allows authenticated forward requests via proxy using this:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net"
)

func main() {

    var proxyAuth *proxy.Auth
    if conf.Username != "" {
        proxyAuth = new(proxy.Auth)
        proxyAuth.User = conf.Username
        proxyAuth.Password = conf.Password
    }

    proxyconn, _ := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", "11.11.11.11:1111", proxyAuth, nil) //returns a Dialer with proxy that can be invoked to connect to another address

    dst := proxyconn.Dial("tcp", "22.33.44.55:6666") //connects to an address via proxy

    dst.Close()
}
```

However it returns a Dialer that then asks to connect a target/ultimate address through this authenticated proxy rather the proxy server itself:

My objective here is to return a net.conn connection with a credentials-authenticated proxy server - something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net"
)

func main() {

    //net.Dial does not have a way to pass Auth creds
    dst := net.Dial("tcp", "22.33.44.55:6666", proxyAuth)

    dst.Close()
}
```

Comment: Why do you want a connection to the proxy?

Comment: Building a native Go proxy Squid-like app. The server side would listen in on localhost and reroute the requests made by the client through an authenticated proxy. Works fine if I have IP authorisation set up with proxy provider as per the first example.

Answer (score 0):

The `net.Dial()` method doesn't concerned with proxy authentication. However, If you want proxy authentication you can set it in header of the request before the call. Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044385/golang-net-dial-userpassipport-gives-no-such-host)

```
dst := net.Dial("tcp", "22.33.44.55:6666")
```

Comment: This seems to be applicable for HTTP forwarding only rather than SOCK5. It's a neat workaround but doesn't not entirely fit my needs unfortunately.